# Regular expression to replace a character on odd repeated occurrences in Python

Tags: python, regex, replace

Can't get a regular expression to replace a character on odd repeated occurrences in Python.

Example:

``````
char = ``...```.....``...`....`````...`
``````

to

```````````
``...``````.....``...``....``````````...``
```````````

on even occurrences doesn't replace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for example:

```````````
>>> import re
>>> s = "`...```.....``...`....`````...`"
>>> re.sub(r'((?<!`)(``)*`(?!`))', r'\1\1', s)
'``...``````.....``...``....``````````...``'
```````````

Comment: Now that I understand OP's question, this makes sense.  +1.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I'm old fashioned (or my regex skills aren't up to par), but this seems to be a lot easier to read:

``````
import re

def double_odd(regex,string):
    """
    Look for groups that match the regex.  Double every second one.
    """
    count = [0]
    def _double(match):
        count[0] += 1
        return match.group(0) if count[0]%2 == 0 else match.group(0)*2
    return re.sub(regex,_double,string)

s = "`...```.....``...`....`````...`"
print double_odd('`',s)
print double_odd('`+',s)
``````

---

It seems that I might have been a little confused about what you were actually looking for.  Based on the comments, this becomes even easier:

```
def odd_repl(match):
    """
    double a match (all of the matched text) when the length of the 
    matched text is odd
    """
    g = match.group(0)
    return g*2 if len(g)%2 == 1 else g

re.sub(regex,odd_repl,your_string)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem double the groups where an odd number of ` are found?

Comment: @sudo_o -- Oh, that's what OP meant.  I thought it was supposed to double the odd groups.  e.g. `re.findall('"+',string)[::2]`.  I'll edit.

Comment: @sudo_o -- Thanks for the head's up.  I was having a hard time matching OP's question with the desired output.  I thought it was a mistake :).

Comment: no problem it wasn't initially obvious what the OP was asking, the +2 upvotes are slightly worrying.. anyway the new solution does the trick so you get +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

This may be not as good as the `regex` solution, but works:

```````````
In [101]: s1=re.findall(r'`{1,}',char)

In [102]: s2=re.findall(r'\.{1,}',char)

In [103]: fill=s1[-1] if len(s1[-1])%2==0 else s1[-1]*2

In [104]: "".join("".join((x if len(x)%2==0 else x*2,y)) for x,y in zip(s1,s2))+fill

Out[104]: '``...``````.....``...``....``````````...``'
```````````

Comment: When I run line 101, 102, 103 and print the variables, it works.  But line 104 is not working for some reason.  Are you able to check this again in an online based Python website and send me a link?  The joins are nifty, but I'm trying to understand how to put this on multiple lines so I understand what it's doing.  thanks!

Comment: Looks like it was missing print around it.  print("".join("".join((x if len(x)%2==0 else x*2,y)) for x,y in zip(s1,s2))+fill)